# want to convert a dictionary to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pandas, image-processing

I am trying to achieve the following output as shown below.

```
immatrix = array(array(Image.open(path2 + '\\' + file)).flatten())
# print(immatrix)
image_dict[file] = immatrix
# print(image_dict)
image_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(image_dict)#, orient='index')#.reset_index()
print(image_df.transpose())
image_df = image_df.rename(index=str, columns={'index':'filename', 0:'image_object'})

 def getPID(row):
     return int(row.split('-')[0])
  image_df['Image_Id'] = image_df.filename.apply(getPID)
```

Am getting an output like.

```
filename            image_object  1   2   3   4   5 ...................... 39998    39999     40000   image_id
8003233-214x261.jpg 214 214 214 214 214 214 214 214 214 ... 216 217 217 217 217 217 217 217 217         8003233 
8003234-214x261.jpg 210 210 210 210 210 210 210 210 211 ... 230 230 230 230 230 230 230 230 230         8003234 
8003235-214x261.jpg 214 215 215 216 216 215 215 214 215 ... 230 230 230 230 230 230 230 230 230         8003235 
8003236-214x261.jpg 215 215 215 215 215 215 215 215 216 ... 225 225 225 225 225 225 225 225 225         8003236
```

Am  trying to achieve output as shown below.

```
filename            image_object                                                                        image_id
8003233-214x261.jpg [214,214,214,214,214,214,214,214,214 ... 216,217,217,217,217,217,217,217,217]       8003233 
8003234-214x261.jpg [210,210,210,210,210,210,210,210,211 ... 230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230]       8003234 
8003235-214x261.jpg [214,215,215,216,216,215,215,214,215 ... 230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230]       8003235 
8003236-214x261.jpg [215,215,215,215,215,215,215,215,216 ... 225,225,225,225,225,225,225,225,225]       8003236
```

Comment: No text as image please? Also please be careful with your grammar.

Comment: @AntonvBR am flattening the matrix of tuples into an array. inserting array into dictionary. from dictionary I am trying to load it into a data frame.

Comment: @user202729 made changes and removed pictures.

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused. I'm removing my comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

able to solve it using.

```
immatrix = Image.open(path2 + '\\' + file)
image_test1 = image.img_to_array(immatrix)   
image_dict[file] = np.asarray(image_test1).reshape(-1)
df1 =  pd.Series(image_dict)
# print(df)

image_df = pd.DataFrame(df1).reset_index()
image_df.columns = ['filename', 'image_object']
# print(type(image_df))
# image_df = pd.DataFrame(image_dict.items(),columns=['filename', 'image_object'])
# image_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(image_dict, orient='index').reset_index()
# image_df = image_df.rename(index=str, columns={'index':'filename', 0:'image_object'})
def getPID(row):
    return int(row.split('-')[0])
image_df['Image_Id'] = image_df.filename.apply(getPID)
```